# R DataTable Recode Many Variables

Tags: r, data.table

```
data=data.frame("cat" = sample(c('a','b'), 100, r=T),
                "dog" = sample(c('a','b'), 100, r=T),
                "bark" = sample(c(1:1000), 100, r=T),
                "fox" = sample(c('a','b'), 100, r=T))

library(data.table)
setDT(data)
```

Is it a possibility to replace 'a' in cat, dog, fox to -9 and 'b' to 9? I wish to do this simultaneously and using the names of the columns in data.table

Comment: are these factor variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are character columns, an option is `set`

```
for(nm1 in c('cat', 'dog', 'fox')) {
   set(data, i = which(data[[nm1]] == 'a'), j= nm1, value = -9)
   set(data, i = which(data[[nm1]] == 'b'), j= nm1, value = 9)
  }
```

---

Or another option is

```
nm1 <- c('cat', 'dog', 'fox')
data[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, function(x)  
          setNames(c(-9, 9), c('a', 'b'))[x]), .SDcols =nm1]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
data=data.frame("cat" = sample(c('a','b'), 100, replace=TRUE),
                "dog" = sample(c('a','b'), 100, replace=TRUE),
                "bark" = sample(c(1:1000), 100, replace=TRUE),
                "fox" = sample(c('a','b'), 100, replace=TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Using the setup in the Note this converts all character columns.

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) if (is.character(x)) c(a = 9, b = -9)[x] else x)]
```

giving:

```
    cat dog bark fox
 1:   9  -9  890  -9
 2:  -9   9  693  -9
 3:   9  -9  641  -9
 4:  -9  -9  995  -9
 5:  -9   9  656   9
 6:   9  -9  709   9
 7:  -9   9  545  -9
 8:  -9   9  595   9
 9:  -9   9  290   9
10:   9  -9  148   9
```

**2)** If you had other character columns and only wanted to change the ones having only 'a' and 'b' then:

```
 DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) 
   if (is.character(x) && all(x %in% c("a", "b"))) c(a = 9, b = -9)[x] else x)]
```

**3) names** This alternative could be used if you prefer specify the column names explicitly.  This modifies `DT` to the desired form.

```
 nms <- c("cat", "dog", "fox")
 DT[, c(nms):=lapply(.SD, function(x) c(a = 9, b = -9)[x]), .SDcols = nms]
```

### Note

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
DT <- data.table("cat" = sample(c('a','b'), 10, TRUE),
                "dog" = sample(c('a','b'), 10, TRUE),
                "bark" = sample(c(1:1000), 10, TRUE),
                "fox" = sample(c('a','b'), 10, TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is:

```
cols <- c("cat", "dog", "fox")
DT[, (cols) := {
    m <- as.matrix(.SD)
    m[m=='a'] <- 9
    m[m=='b'] <- -9
    as.data.table(m)
}, .SDcols=cols]
```